# Is GWT compatible with app-engine's multitenancy support

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

Just looking for confirmation that the GWT RPCs play well with app-engine's new multi-tenancy support based on name-spaces.

Comment: Not sure why you where down voted twice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use multi-tenancy in your GWT-RPC, but it will not be just configuration. You can use per-user multi-tenancy setting NameSpace using filter, but do not forget that if you start AsyncTasks from gwt-rpc calls you will not have valid user in tasks requests so you will need to figure out how to choose namespace in tasks.

Comment: Thank you. I think that was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The two technologies are very compatiable.  I have been using them together for a long time.  In fact there are some syntatic sugar that makes them easy to be used together, such are RPC calls.  Plus now your server and client code are in the same language.  Using eclipse and the setup that google developed for eclipse and GWT/AppEngine I have all the code in one project with a client, server and shared code.  The client and Shared code gets compiled with GWT and the server and shared code get compiled for AppEngine.

I hope this helps.
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/appengine

Michael

Comment: I have two sites running with AppEngine and GWT as the only technologies used.

Comment: The question was specifically about multi-tenancy on app-engine (using the built-in support based on name-spaces).  I also have gwt applications working on app-engine, but wanted to confirm that the gwt RPC model worked with app-engine multi-tenancy.

Comment: As long as you understand that a RPC call can go to any server on app-engine (even from the same user); therefore you can't rely on the memcache to save needed info for other RPC calls.  Either pass it back to the client to send again (not that ideal) or save it in the datastore.

Comment: that's a cache issue entirely separate from multi-tenancy. I'm not concerned about stale data, I'm concerned about having 3 organizations using my site as separate tenants and ensuring that they cannot see each other's data.  I could do this myself programmatically, but App-Engine advertises built-in support for multi-tenancy.  See http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/08/multi-tenancy-support-high-performance_17.html

Answer (score 0):

As long as your server-side implementations correctly handle the multi-tenancy, you'll be fine.

There is no additional load to using multi-tenancy with GWT-RPC, but there is additional load using multi-tenancy and you won't be able to *avoid* that with GWT-RPC.